# Does the Bible provide an age of consent?

Tags: marriage, morality

I was debating with my Muslim friend on the immorality of Mohammad marrying Aisesha at an incredibly young age (Sahih al-Bukhari 5134), in which he responded that nowhere in the Bible does it give an age of consent or when someone reaches adulthood. Are there any Bible verses which give an age of consent or tell us when someone reaches adulthood?

Comment: No, there is no such number given, because it is a common sense thing and the bible does not have to explicitly condemn child sex. The absence of such laws doesnt mean it approves it.

Comment: Even though the Bible doesn't have an explicit age of consent, it was understood by everyone that you have to be a certain age to engage in lovemaking: "I passed by you again and looked on you; **you were at the age for love**. I spread the edge of my cloak over you, and covered your nakedness: I pledged myself to you and entered into a covenant with you, says the Lord God, and you became mine." (Ezekiel 16:8 NRSVCE)

Comment: _Doth not nature teach_ . . . . . .  ? (In this, as in other, matters of nature.) 1 Corinthians 11:14.

Comment: King Josiah had Eliakim when he was 14 or 15 and Jehoahaz when he was 16. (These can be derived from the dates given in 2Kings 22 and 23)

Comment: Muhammed also made a law that none of his wives could marry after he died.  Aisha was only about 19 years old when he died yet she had to live as a widow for the rest of her life.. not very considerate or kind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm limiting this response strictly to the question of does under-age marriage occur in the bible? Here I take the 'age of consent' to mean marriage. This isn't to be interpreted within the context to the background to the question, i.e. relating to the Qur'an (Koran), that is for a different site altogether.

There is no under-age marriage in the bible within their social norm, i.e. the age they were considered adults. On the contrary there were a number of "social structures" (a euphemism for murderous revenge in some cases) throughout the bible to block under-age marriage. Point 2 directly speaks about the issue of "age of consent", points 1 and 3 are background and not directly relevant.

1. Jacob's marriage to Rachel makes it clear there was a system of patriarchy that blocked the marriage for years.
2. The Song of Songs 8:7 and 8:10 makes it clear a woman's right of choice was important, in addition her brothers would protect her against under age marriage

> <sup>8</sup> We have a little sister *who in our view is too young for marriage*. What shall we do for our sister on the day she is spoken for?
> <sup>9</sup> If she is a wall, we will build towers of silver on her. If she is a door, we will enclose her with panels of cedar.

**Note** the *italicised* words have been paraphrased. One of the two interpretations of Song of Songs is Solomon wants the young woman as another wife. She turns him down for an elusive shepherd Song of Songs 8:7,

> If one were to give all the wealth of one’s house* for love, it would be utterly scorned.

*, under this interpretation the house is King Solomon's. She speaks later of a what appears to be Solomon's "brides price" of a 1000 shekels (a lot money), which she rejects (Song of Songs 8:12). Thus, its the woman's choice even against a king, and she also disputes her brothers' opinion she's too young to marry.

3. The protection of the sister from sex crimes by the retribution of her brothers is a repeat theme of the bible. The first example Genesis 34:24 onwards is an attempt by the perpetrator at a forced marriage by the rape of Dinah. The brothers response is let's just say ensure the suitor (perpetrator) is ineligible. In addition, the failure to punish Amnon for the rape of Tamar 2 Samuel 13, who was Absalom's sister, led to his murder 2 Samuel 13:29 at Absalom's command.

Point 3 in particular is well terrible, but under-age marriage - this being the social norm within the bible - doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, "No." That begs the questions, what does the Bible say about the timing of marriage? A lot!

The Bible offers a guide to life with directions of varying flavor. Some rules are statutory, with special numbers and days and years counted out. Much of the sacrificial system was of this nature. Other rules are wisdom-based. The latter give guidelines that may depend upon the situation for implementation. Within the wisdom-based rules are riddles and parables. God did this as a test, to see who is willing to study His Word carefully enough to uncover what is hidden and put it into practice.

When contemplating an age of consent for marriage, there are many considerations. Here are some:

1. physical maturity (reaching puberty)
2. emotional maturity
3. occupational maturity (knowing how to cook, keep house, grow crops, care for children)
4. relational maturity (friendships as well as marriage)
5. availability of a suitable mate
6. God's will

The first is obvious. Many cultures work around the fifth by pre-arranged marriages, giving the couple enough time to grow up before marriage while securing an agreeable arrangement.

The sixth is mysterious and not subject to rules. It is covered by *Song of Songs*.

```
I adjure you, O daughters of Jerusalem,
    by the gazelles or the does of the field,
that you not stir up or awaken love
    until it pleases. (Song of Songs 2:7)
```

That leaves the second, third and fourth: emotional, occupational and relational. People do not mature at the same rate in these areas. Thus it takes wise families and cultures to recognize when a person is old enough to get married.

There is a Bible passage that touches on this. Ecclesiastes 3 gives a framework for human development. It divides life into seven phases, each phase consisting of four "times". A person who reaches the 28th time is fully mature and can serve as a leader in their community. A person who reaches the 12th-15th time is ready for marriage. There is a large window, to account for variations in how fast people mature.

The seven phases are:

1. **Security**. Birth to age 7. A time to be born, die, plant, uproot.
2. **Ability**. Ages 7 to 14. A time to kill, heal, break down, build up.
3. **Stability**. Ages 14 to 21. A time to weep, laugh, mourn and dance.
4. **Amity**. Ages 21 to 28. A time to cast away stones, gather stones, embrace and refrain.
5. **Opportunity**. Ages 28 to 35. A time to seek, lose, keep, cast away.
6. **Community**. Ages 35 to 42. A time to tear, mend, keep silence, speak.
7. **Loyalty**. Ages 42 to 49. A time to love, hate, for war and peace.

Each of the times is a parable, some more obvious than others. For example uprooting is becoming a refugee due to war, famine or social exile and undermines an infant's security. Break down and build up are phrases I learned from the Navy and describe basic training, corresponding to parents teaching their children life skills and requiring chores. Learning these skills is the first part of acquiring occupational maturity.

The critical times for emotional maturity are weep and laugh, when teenagers learn verbal self control, and mourn and dance, when they learn physical self control.

The first two critical times for relational maturity are casting and gathering stones, which means cooperation in the physical tasks of life. This can mean in friendships, dating relationships or marriage.

The next two critical times for relational maturity are the times to embrace and refrain from embracing. This is when a young adult must master choosing healthy and rejecting unhealthy friendships and eventually marriage partners.

Once married, the next challenges are finding and keeping a job (seeking and losing opportunities) and acquiring, saving or spending money and resources (keeping and casting away resources). In our day, people are choosing to wait longer to get married, trying to establish themselves in their careers. Perhaps they are heeding this parable: "Prepare your work outside; get everything ready for yourself in the field, and after that build your house." (Proverbs 24:27) That parable means to make progress in your career (preparing your fields) before building your house (starting a family).

To round out the phases of life, the **Community** phase is challenging. Tearing and mending is about the fracture of friendships and learning forgiveness, while being quiet is for listening, which comes before speaking. They are about maintaining open lines of communication.

Finally, the **Loyalty** phase is the ultimate one. Love and hate are our attitudes of loyalty: who is on my side and who is on the other side. War and peace are our demonstrations of loyalty: warring against enemies and living at peace with our friends.

In such a framework for human growth and development, the time for marriage becomes clear.

- In prosperous times and for a mature person with wise and loving parents and good family support, "a time to dance" can be a wedding dance at age 19-21.
- For a person slower to mature, whether because of rebelliousness, poor parenting, poverty or genetic factors, age 22-27.
- In times of famine, economic depression, war, or other disruptions, it is better to wait until firmly established in a good paying job. Thus marriage should wait until age 28-31.

By reading the circumstances of your background, community and personal development, you (or your parents) have the tools you need to read from God's plan for the times of life and decide when it is wise to get married.

Of course, sometimes the whole world gets stuck in one of these times and the choice is taken from you. The people of Ukraine are stuck in "a time for war". During the COVID-19 pandemic, the whole world was stuck in "a time to refrain from embracing" due to social distancing. With all that going on, God was wise not to set a hard and fast count of years. We would be wise to follow His guidelines, though.

Comment: In Jesus' time Jewish maidens were marriageable at 13-14.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Bible definitely gives an age of adulthood. The age is **twenty years**.

Numbers 14:26-31 KJV

> <sup>**26**</sup> And the Lord spake unto Moses and unto Aaron, saying, <sup>**27**</sup> How long shall I bear with this evil congregation, which murmur against me? I have heard the murmurings of the children of Israel, which they murmur against me. <sup>**28**</sup> Say unto them, As truly as I live, saith the Lord, as ye have spoken in mine ears, so will I do to you: <sup>**29**</sup> Your carcases shall fall in this wilderness; and all that were numbered of you, according to your whole number, from twenty years old and upward which have murmured against me. <sup>**30**</sup> Doubtless ye shall not come into the land, concerning which I sware to make you dwell therein, save Caleb the son of Jephunneh, and Joshua the son of Nun. <sup>**31**</sup> But your little ones, which ye said should be a prey, them will I bring in, and they shall know the land which ye have despised.

As for the age of consent, there is none specific. The father of the damsel in the Old Testament was charged with keeping his daughter pure until she was married.

Deuteronomy 22:13-21 KJV

> <sup>**13**</sup> If any man take a wife, and go in unto her, and hate her, <sup>**14**</sup> And give occasions of speech against her, and bring up an evil name upon her, and say, I took this woman, and when I came to her, I found her not a maid: <sup>**15**</sup> Then shall the father of the damsel, and her mother, take and bring forth the tokens of the damsel's virginity unto the elders of the city in the gate: <sup>**16**</sup> And the damsel's father shall say unto the elders, I gave my daughter unto this man to wife, and he hateth her; <sup>**17**</sup> And, lo, he hath given occasions of speech against her, saying, I found not thy daughter a maid; and yet these are the tokens of my daughter's virginity. And they shall spread the cloth before the elders of the city. <sup>**18**</sup> And the elders of that city shall take that man and chastise him; <sup>**19**</sup> And they shall amerce him in an hundred shekels of silver, and give them unto the father of the damsel, because he hath brought up an evil name upon a virgin of Israel: and she shall be his wife; he may not put her away all his days. <sup>**20**</sup> But if this thing be true, and the tokens of virginity be not found for the damsel: <sup>**21**</sup> Then they shall bring out the damsel to the door of her father's house, and the men of her city shall stone her with stones that she die: because she hath wrought folly in Israel, to play the whore in her father's house: so shalt thou put evil away from among you.

The Bible forbids sex outside of marriage, or fornication (1 Corinthians 7:1-3).

The Bible does provide an age of adulthood.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanna add one thing to the fact that you all say the bible doesn't condone child marriages or underage (sex) lovemaking.

Numbers 31:17-18 KJV

> <sup>**17**</sup> Now therefore kill every male among the little ones, and kill every woman that hath known man by lying with him. <sup>**18**</sup> But all the women children, that have not known a man by lying with him, keep alive for yourselves.

Numbers 31:18 Jubilee Bible 2000

> But all the female children that have not known a man by lying with him keep alive for yourselves.

Numbers 31:18 Living Bible

> Only the little girls may live; you may keep them for yourselves.

Some explaining the verse
"NIV: The New American Commentary – An Exegetical And Theological Exposition of Holy Scripture:

> … Only the young girls would be allowed to live so that they may be taken as wives or slaves by Israelite men, according to the principles of holy war (Deut 20:13-14; 21:10-14). By this, they could be brought under the umbrella of the covenant community of faith.

Isaac was born when Sarah was 90 years old (Genesis 17:15-22). Sarah died at the age of 127, this would make Isaac 37 at the time of her mother’s demise (Genesis 23:1-3). Rebecca was born when Isaac was in his late 30s (Genesis 22). Isaac married Rebecca when he was 40 years old (Genesis 25:20) This means, that Rebekah was between the ages of 3 to 10 when she was married off to Isaac.

Comment: *"Rebecca was born when Isaac was in his late 30s (Genesis 22)."* Which part of Genesis 22 says that?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score -1):

God speaks through his creation and from nature the time when a man or a woman completes showing body changes that prepare him or her for reproduction can be considered the time God destined for marriage.